# Sufficient conditions to show $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}$, using vector identities

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I would like to prove that two finite-dimensional vector fields $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x},t)$ and $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x},t)$, with $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$, are the same vector field, i.e. $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}$

Due to the nature of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ expressions, might be very easy to show for example that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}$ or that $\nabla\times\mathbf{A}=\nabla\times\mathbf{B}$.

Are there some sufficient conditions involving nabla operator $\nabla$, or vector identities in general, to show that two given vector are the same vector (or they just differ from a constant)?

Comment: If you are solving a particular problem, it would help *a lot* if you could give more details about the problem you are actually solving. It may turn out that you just think you need to overcome this step, while it actually turns out you need to do something completely different.

Comment: Do you means that $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are vector fields?

Comment: @EmilioNovati yes, and also to respond to StinkingBishop i could say they are function of (x,y,z,t) - should i add these informations to the question text?

Comment: Well, from @EmilioNovati's answer it looks like you cannot say pretty much anything about $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ as they may differ by a curl of an arbitrary vector field or by a gradient of an arbitrary scalar field (if I am interpreting it correctly, I am not an expert...)... But only you can tell which other conditions you know about that could be helpful here.

Comment: @StinkingBishop The thing is that the identities i'm going to verify are more than one so this is the most specific i can say (they all involve the field of electrodynamics but i wanted to ask the question in general terms, for vector fields in general), EmilioNovati's answer in my case is actually useful since adding some extra vectors into the expression might 'unlock' some combinations with the present ones

Answer (score 1):

Remember that for a vector field $\mathbf V$:
$$
\nabla \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf V)=0
$$
and$$
\nabla \times(\nabla  \mathbf V)=0
$$
so:
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf A=\nabla \cdot(\mathbf A+\nabla \times \mathbf V)
$$
and
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf A=\nabla \times(\mathbf A+\nabla \mathbf V)
$$